# Can SQL Server 2016 R Services connect to SAS, SPSS, URLs etc?

Tags: sql-server-2016, r

The **RevoScaleR** package of SQL Server R Services (Microsoft R Server) has functions that allow you to connect to SAS, SPSS, HDFS and text files. 
My question is:

1. Can R Services connect to SAS/SPSS to directly import data from SAS into SQL Server 2016, or do I have to download the SAS/SPSS dataset into a .SAS file and then import it via the RxImport function?
2. Can I directly import datasets from a URL into SQL Server 2016?

Comment: See my answer to your [other question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140852/can-sql-server-2016-r-services-be-used-to-connect-to-hadoop-data), I think the same applies.  It would be unusual (not impossible) to have a SQL Server facing the internet - you might be safer with a fileshare ; )

Comment: What happens if I don't want to keep any of my data on the cloud?
Can the RevoScaleR functions connect to SAS/SPSS to directly import data from SAS into SQL Server 2016 database? Is it possible?

What are the alternatives?